# Congruence lattice of a partial algebra is algebraic

Tags: lattice-orders, universal-algebra

A partial operation on a nonempty set $A$ is a map $f:\mathrm{dom}(f,A)\to A$ where $\mathrm{dom}(f,A)\subseteq A^n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$. A partial algebra is an ordered pair $(A,P)$ where $A$ is a nonempty set and $P$ is a set of partial operations on $A$. A congruence on $\mathfrak{A}=(A,P)$ is an equivalence relation $\sim$ such that if $f\in P$, $\mathrm{dom}(f,A)\subseteq A^n$, $(a_1,\ldots, a_n)$,$(b_1,\ldots,b_n)\in\mathrm{dom}(f,A)$, and $a_1\sim b_1, \ldots, a_n\sim b_n$, then $f(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\sim f(b_1,\ldots, b_n)$. Let $\mathrm{Con}\mathfrak{A}$ denote the set of all congruences on $\mathfrak{A}$. I want to prove that $\mathrm{Con}\mathfrak{A}$ is an algebraic lattice.

The problem is that the join of two partial algebra congruences (as equivalence relations) is not necessarily a congruence. Preferably, I would like a proof that avoids the use of directed unions or closure operators.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use this definition of congruence relation of a partial algebra?  For partial algebras, it might be better to consider "strong congruence relations." See, e.g. [Berman's thesis.](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17739547/diss/berman-phd-thesis.pdf) (The lattice of strong congruence relations of a partial algebra is algebraic. In fact, given a partial algebra, you can find an algebra whose congruence lattice is isomorphic to that of the partial algebra.)

Comment: The strengthening of your definition, to that of a "strong congruence", would be: if $a_1\sim b_1, \dots, a_n\sim b_n$ and $f(a_1, \dots, a_n)$ exists, then $f(b_1, \dots, b_n)$ exists and $f(a_1, \dots, a_n) \sim f(b_1, \dots, b_n)$.

Comment: I'm just reading through Gratzer and Schmidt's 1963 paper and this is Theorem 1. I wasn't exactly sure how to prove it without an understanding of the join of two (or more) congruences.